# Get schema name of the currently executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there a way to retrieve schema owner of a store procedure from within its implementation?

The stored procs are `World.Perform_Task` and `Universe.Perform_Task`. When the stored procedure gets executed, I need to retrieve name of the schema to perform some schema level tasks and also lookup objects (tables, columns, etc.) in that schema.

I tried `Schema_Name()` but it returns the default schema of the logged in user (which is `dbo`) not the schema owner of the stored procedure.

How do I get the schema of the executing stored procedure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you go...

```
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

Links to MSDN:

- [OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx)

> Returns the database schema name for schema-scoped objects

- [@@PROCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174408.aspx)

> Returns the object identifier (ID) of the current Transact-SQL module.